# Any API for getting deleted IDs from the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, synchronization

In attempting to keep photo URLs in sync between my application and Facebook, I'd like to detect if a photo is deleted from an album.  Is there any API for getting something like recently deleted IDs, or is the only option to walk the collection (in this case, an album) and compare the IDs to ones stored in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there isn't an API for getting deleted IDs. You would, as you mention, need to walk over all the photos to figure out which one has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks.  Would be nice to have!  Think about adding it. :)